# How to get the variable value on the scope of subscribe?

Tags: google-maps, typescript, scope

How can i get the value of counter variable on the subscribe() in this code snippet?

```
let counter:number = 0;
        for(let poi of this.pois) {             
            let coord = poi.LocationCoordinates.replace(' ', '').split(',');
            let that = this;
            this.map.addMarker({
                icon: 'marker.png',
                animation: 'DROP',
                position: {
                    lat: coord[0],
                    lng: coord[1]
                }
            }).then(marker => {     
                console.log(counter);                               
                marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {                       
                    that.goToSlide(counter);                        
                });
                counter++;
            });         
        }
```

On the console before subscribing the event, it returns the correct value of the counter, but inside the subscribe it is always the last value of the counter variable.
I have tried to use the bind(), and pass the counter through a function created but with no success. This is a problem with the scope, but i can't figure out how to resolve it.

Comment: It always prints the **correct** value, as you're increasing it with each call to `then`. What should be the correct value? 0? If you always expect 0, do not use a variable, just use 0 or a constant.

Comment: on that.goToSlide(counter) the counter value is always 12 (that corresponds to the length of my object).
What i want is to have the goToSlide function called with 0, 1, 2 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the call to your callback in `subscribe` is asynchronous, while the execution of the for loop is not. Your callback makes a closure with the `counter` variable, not its value. But `counter` changes. Before the callback you are passing to `subscribe` can execute once, your loop has finished and `counter` has changed. When those callbacks execute, you always get the latest available value when you call `goToSlide`.

You need to make a local copy of that value that belongs to the scope of the callback passed to `then`:

```
 }).then(marker => {     
     console.log(counter);   
     let _counter = counter; // local copy                            
     marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {                       
         this.goToSlide(_counter);                        
     });
     counter++;
 });
```

Now, the arrow function in `subscribe` is bound to a different `_counter` variable each time, and `_counter` is never modified, so you get the desired value.

I also changed `that` to `this` inside `subscribe`, because arrow functions's `this` is automatically bound to the `this` in the scope they are defined in. So no need for `that`.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much, it makes perfect sense.